# Assess risk with or without exising countermeasures

Tags: risk-analysis

I recently had a discussion with a coworker about the of a risk analysis. When doing a risk assessment you typically identify threats, assess them and then identify the countermeasures. I my opinion it is better to assess the risk of a threat without the existing countermeasures and then identify and assess the countermeasures and their effectiveness.

For example when assessing the risk of a connection to the cloud being eavesdropped, should one consider the risk with or without the TLS that is actually in place according to the design?

My opinion is that it is better to not consider the countermeasure. This to assess the effectiveness and being able to document the important of this countermeasure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to consider the objective of you risk analysis. You want to assess the threats and know if these constitute a risk to your assets. So (TL;DR:) yes you should include current measures.

To do the risk analysis, if we based ourselves onto ISO27k models, you will define a risk formula, assess your vulnerability and exposure to the treats, then get a level of risk through computation of this formula. If this level is higher than your acceptance level, you have to act on it.

It does not matter whether you include current measure in or not. Without the countermeasure, it should raise the level above that threshold and force you to add additional information about countermeasure you place to reduce the risk. However, it's probably better to already take in account the existing measures and have the resulting risk factor already ok (don't add to your work).

The effectiveness of the countermeasure is a totally different aspect of the risk management, and it should appear quantitatively in other documents of your risk management system. Should they fail to be efficient, you would have to re-evaluate the risks and change them.

"the risk of a connection" is not a real risk element btw. "Data theft" or "User impersonation" are threats to your business. These threats can arises because of the vulnerability of the connection (among other thing). This vulnerability has a specific occurrence probability and a given impact if successful on your business. The goal of the risk analysis is by identifying vulnerabilities, related threats, impacts and plausibility of an attack success, if you suffer a great cost or not. If yes, you have to to something about it.

To conclude, I see no real benefit to not take into account the already in place countermeasures for the risk analysis. If you are worried about efficiency, you should refer to the indicators of your ISMS.

Comment: You say ""the risk of a connection" is not a real risk element" why not? do you mean that this is to detailed a threat?

Comment: The risk might be "data theft". The threat is the "attack on the connection". The vulnerability might be the possibility of the connection to be "Man in the Middle"-ed. . And the impact could be, "loss of credibility and money". The risk of a connection has no meaning by itself, are you "at risk to be connected to" ? I think this is the point of the service.